# Window animation on loaded if window state is maximized

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm applying a sliding in animation when window is loaded with the following code :

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0" Duration="0:0:1">

                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="parent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Left)" From="1920" To="0" AutoReverse="true" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>


        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

It works fine,but when i enable WindowState="Maximized" in the main window,The animation does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a limitation in Windows, not WPF - you can't change a window's position when it's maximized. The animation actually does run (the `Left` value changes), but it has not effect.

What you can do is animate the window while it's in the `Normal` state and maximized it once the animation completes:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        Name="parent"
        WindowState="Normal"
        Top="0"
        Left="{x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}"
        Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}"
        Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenHeight}"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignData ViewModel}">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="parent"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Left)"
                                         To="0"
                                         Duration="0:0:1" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="parent"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="WindowState">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static WindowState.Maximized}"
                                                    KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
```

Note this code will only work properly for systems with a single monitor. Otherwise you'd have to initialize all the screen width/height values using the Windows Forms `Screen` class.